# one class instance

Tags: php

is there a way to prevent the instance of the same class in a PHP script?

```
$user = new User();


$user2 = new User();  // I want to catch another instance of the user class and throw an exception
```

I have tried creating a static variable and manipulating it with a static function:

```
User::instance()
```

but that doesn't stop me from doing:

```
$user = new User();
```

Comment: I do not agree with @Tordek, I think singleton are very useful when they are use the righr way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
class Foo {
  static function instance() {
    static $inst = null;
    if ($inst === null) { $inst = new self; }
    return $inst;
  }
  private function __construct() { }
  private function __clone() { }
}
```

Comment: is this the same as doing it the singleton way?

Comment: Needs `__wakeup()` to effectively prevent unserializing additional instances. People always seem to miss that.

Answer (score 6):

Without changing object semantics, you could keep a static counter in the constructor.  This is not a singleton, as it's not globally available, just only instantiatable once...

```
class Foo {
    private static $counter = 0;
    final public function __construct() {
        if (self::$counter) {
            throw new Exception('Cannot be instantiated more than once');
        }
        self::$counter++;
        // Rest of your constructor code goes here
    }
    // Rest of class
}
```

Comment: Down voter: care to explain?  It answers what the OP asked for.  It's not adding new side-effects (like a singleton would, introducing global availability of the object) and it still solves what the OP asked for.  So really, it's the only answer here that actually answers the question without adding new assumptions...

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for a singleton in PHP.

http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/php-singleton-design-pattern-050729/page1.html

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've tried to do this, but have you tried making your __construct method protected or private?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about php syntax and language features, but you could have a static field in your class of type `User` that will keep an instance of your `User` object. And make the constructor throw an error. That way when you want an instance of your class you can call `User.Instance` and that will return the only existent instance. If you attempt to instantiate the object it will throw an error.

In C# it would look something like this. As I mentioned, I don't know the php syntax.

```
class User
{
  private static User instance = null;

  public User()
  {
      //throw exception
  }

  public static User Instance
  {
    get 
    {
       if(instance == null)
       {
          instance = new User();
       }
       return instance;
    }
  }

}
```